# Kafka Connect: No suitable driver found

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying Kafka with Postgres Sink using JDBC-sink connector.

**Exception:**

```
INFO Unable to connect to database on attempt 1/3. Will retry in 10000 ms. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:91)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casb
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:85)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getValidConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:68)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:56)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Sink.properties:**

```
name=test-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=fp_test
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casb
connection.user=admin
connection.password=***
auto.create=true
```

I have set `plugin.path=/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`

On **/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc** I have the following files:

`kafka-connect-jdbc-4.0.0.jar` , `postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc41.jar`, `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar` and some other jars that basically come packaged along with confluent.

I then downloaded postgres-jdbc driver jar `postgresql-42.2.2.jar`, copied it in the same folder and tried again. Still the same exception.

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: What is the Java `CLASSPATH` setting? Are you running connect standalone or distributed? What confluent version?

Comment: I have set `CLASSPATH` to `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` as well and I am running connect in distributed mode. My confluent version is 3.1.1

Comment: Okay, well 1) `plugin.path` was added in 4.0, which would explain why that doesn't work 2) how did you get `kafka-connect-jdbc-4.0.0.jar`, and are you sure you want to run that version with an older version of Confluent?

Comment: Okay so maybe I am wrong. I may have confluent version 4. How can I be sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `plugin.path=/usr/share/java` and `CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/` solved the issue.